# Unable to get the flutter fragment programmatically as the host project uses androidx libs which are incompatible with v4

Tags: flutter, androidx

Have an issue with the FlutterFragment which extends from android.support.v4.app.Fragment support libs **instead of androidx**.

**So I am unable to get the flutter fragment programmatically as the host project uses androidx libs which are incompatible with v4.**

*These are my settings for both host and the flutter modules:*

**- gradle.properties ( host project )**

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

**- settings.gradle** ( host project )

```
evaluate(new File(
        settingsDir.parentFile,
        '/flutterlib/.android/include_flutter.groovy'
))
```

**- build.gradle** ( app module )

```
implementation project(':flutter')
```

**- pubspec.yaml** ( flutter project )

```
 module:
    androidX: true
    androidPackage: com.example.project_flutter
    iosBundleIdentifier: com.example.project_flutter
```

**- .android/gradle.properties**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.enableR8=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

**- .android/Flutter/build.gradle** ( tried to add the androidx.legacy/annotation libs )

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0'
}
```

I've checked all of the above and still the FlutterFragment continue extending from v4 support libs.

Additionally, i've checked the FlutterFragment.java.tmpl from which I believe the framework should generate either v4 or androidx FlutterFragment class and it does contain the correct condition

```
{{#androidX}}
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
{{/androidX}}
{{^androidX}}
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
{{/androidX}}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Really appreciate any input on this.

```
- This is my flutter doctor -v output:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.7, on Mac OS X 10.15.2 19C57, locale en-IL)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.7 at /Users/user/Projects/flutter
    • Framework revision 9f5ff2306b (13 days ago), 2020-01-26 22:38:26 -0800
    • Engine revision a67792536c
    • Dart version 2.7.0
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
    • All Android licenses accepted.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.3.1, Build version 11C504
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 43.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.1)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin version 43.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 191.6183.88
[✓] VS Code (version 1.42.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.8.1
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • SM G950F • 988a1b47315139564e • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)
• No issues found!
```

Comment: Same proble here) It seems that this bug cuase FlutterFragment builder to ignore parameters, such transparency and renderMode